# Bootstrap Modal form loading with dynamically created button

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I am targeting "model-body" section to load the dynamically created table in update.php, but when i click on the edit button,nothing is happens and then page becomes hanged.Can someone please advise what is missing ?

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="Modal1" aria-labelledby="Modal-Edit 
  Form" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
 <div class="modal-content">
 <div class="modal-header">
 <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria- 
 label="Close">
 <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
 </button>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
 <table cellpadding="10px" width="100%" id="modal1">
 </table>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
$(document).on("click", ".edit-btn", function(e) {
$("#Modal1").toggle("show");
var peid = $(this).data("eid"); 
 $.ajax({
url: "update.php",
type: "POST",
 data: {
 id: peid
     },
 success: function(data) {
 $("#Modal1 table").html(data);
 }
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click", ".edit-btn", function(e) {
 $("#Modal1").toggle("show");
});
```

try this.

Comment: Code-only answers are strongly discouraged. Please [include an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/13138364) of how and why this solves the problem. This will help future readers to better understand your solution. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/30166039)

Comment: i have tried this before, but doesnt work.   $(document).on("click", ".edit-btn", function(e) {
 $("#Modal1").toggle("show");
});

Comment: problems solved, thank you